# List of an interface inside a collection

Tags: java, collections, interface

I have a hashmap where the key is  UpgradePartType and the Value is an
   List of UpgradeParts. Why can't I put a List of EnginePart in the hashmap when EnginePart implements UpgradePart?

it works if I have a hashmap with values of IUpgradePart when i put en EnginePart

```
      private HashMap<UpgradePartType, ArrayList<IUpgradePart>> purchasedUpgrades;
       ...
      purchasedUpgrades  = new HashMap<UpgradePartType,ArrayList<IUpgradePart>>();
      purchasedUpgrades.put(UpgradePartType.Engine,new ArrayList<EnginePart>());

      ...        
      public enum EnginePart implements IUpgradePart{
      Stock,PortPolish,Bore,Tune
      }

      ...
```

also is it normal to have a blank interface?, I feel like there should be something in here

```
      public interface IUpgradePart{

      }
```

Comment: Empty interfaces are pretty usual. They're called *marker interfaces*

Comment: Have a look at [Bounded Type Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)